# SPO How to set permission for a specific column in a list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, permissions, column

I have a list contain 3 columns:

Ex: A,B,C

The **Admin** can **create/edit and delete all columns.**

My requirement is: **The invited user** can also **create/edit and delete except of column C**.

He can see it but **he should not be able edit or delete it**.

So how to achieve this functionality.

Is it possible to set **column level permission** in SharePoint Online?

Comment: To give you a short answer - no. Not OOTB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**.

It is not possible using OOTB functionalities as SharePoint **does not support the column level permissions**. SharePoint only supports unique permissions until item level.

Comment: Thank you @Ganesh Sanap